# Unable to implement logstash pipeline for kaka as input and s3 as output with each message persisted as individual file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, logstash

How can I create logstash (https://www.elastic.co/logstash/) pipeline to transfer a single individual message to AWS s3 bucket individual files with the file name as one of the attributes of Kafka message.

I am able to set up a simple pipeline using the following.
I am using s3 output plugin:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html

and Kafka input plugin :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html

```
input {
 kafka {
 bootstrap_servers => "mykafkaserver:9092"
 topics => "document"
 group_id => "xLogAna1"
 auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
 max_poll_records => 1
 fetch_max_bytes=>10
 }
}
output {
   s3{
     access_key_id => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     secret_access_key => "SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS"
     region => "eu-west-1"
     bucket => "<my-documnt-bucket>"
     size_file => 1
     time_file => 5
     codec => "plain"
   }
 }
```

Since I want individual messages in individual files i tweaked the parameters max_poll_records  and fetch_max_bytes to get individual messages but it's no help. In resultant s3 files, i am getting numerous kafka messages

Comment: Can you clarify why exactly you'd want to pollute S3 with a bunch of tiny files? Sounds like you should be using a document database, or Elasticsearch, not S3

Comment: This are message payloads which needs to be replayed in downstream error scenarios ( within a duration which is greater than Kafka retention period).

Comment: That doesn't really answer why you cannot write more than one message per file, though. You will still need to download the S3 file, then read it. At which point, you can iterate over multiple records rather than just sending the whole file text as one event

Comment: You could also still use a database, like I said, to filter the records by a timestamp, then iterate the records from the database client to marshal into Kafka records to produce

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding... This can not be written to database as this messages also contain binaray data which can sometime be of size greater than 100mb, regarding writing to individual file, it was for facilitating search in constant n time, because the file name will always be the search key which is part of the json

Comment: Many databases can hold binary blobs of arbitrary size. You really shouldn't have 100mb records in Kafka, anyway. But, you do realize that the `size_file` is in bytes, right and having data larger than that setting here is what's causing more than one file to be written? But why use logstash instead of Kafka Connect's S3 sink?

Comment: Thanks again, yeah this is a legacy application that is writing to kafka, and it's out of our control, definitely as suggested let me evaluate the  KafkaConnectS3 sink.